# QGIS: How to speed up raster processing?

Tags: qgis, raster, qgis-processing, geoprocessing, parallel-processing

Is there any way to speed up raster processing in QGIS? I have seen discussion about speeding up rendering and querying, but not processing.

I am using SAGA tools to calculate morphometrics and the calculations are taking extremely long. I am maxing out my CPU. Does QGIS parallel process using all available cores by default?

Comment: If you are maxing out your CPU I would say your CPU is the bottleneck and not SAGA processing.

Comment: Yes. I am using a Mac and 'Activity Monitor' confirms that I am using all four cores available on my computer for processing.

Comment: CPU running at 100% is a good sign only if the code makes CPU to do something that makes sense. Without a test case it is impossible to say why your process is so slow.